# What's the perspective on my beloved Textures from Bluesky (refused letter to: president@bluesky.com)

Tags: mac

Allegra Smith,

I found your email in a discussion thread about the loss of Textures, the one and only great TeX/LaTeX implementation for the Mac. I was so sorry to read about the very unfortunate fate the author had to endure. Textures was such a great tool to do serious writing with. In fact I still use Textures on an older PowerMac G5 when I have to write something meaningful. However, I would still love to see some kind of a follow-up that would come close to the original superb thoughtful implementation of a TexX/LaTeX writing tool!

Is there any chance that the work will be taken up and revitalized? I am still in hope that this will happen some day... or am I simply dreaming?

Maybe you could inform me a bit about the present state of affairs of that project. I am in Switzerland, actually designing and writing about lecture demonstrations we show at our basic physics courses at the University of Bern.

Thank you

Sincerely yours

Urs Lauterburg

University of Bern
Physikalisches Institut
Sidlerstrasse 5
3012 Bern
Switzerland

Tel: +41 31 631 44 88

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not the correct addressee for letters to the publisher of a non-open TeX implementation.

Comment: Whilst I understand your wish to communication with the former authors of BlueSky, as noted already this is not the appropriate place: it's not a forum and there is no real way this can be regarded as a question which is answerable.

Comment: On the question itself, and pure speculation: I suspect that it's very unlikely that further work will be done on this. The wide availability of TeX Live and a range of editors coupled with the speed of modern processors makes it difficult to see a significant 'market' (paying clients or simply users of a free approach) for other TeX systems. (There are also non-TeX pipelines for serious journal work, _etc._)

Comment: @Schweinebacke I think the 'openness' of the software doesn't really impact here: 'Will software X continue to be developed?' is problematic irrespective of the nature of X (See LEd, TeXniccenter, for example.)